# How to combine several csv in one with identical rows?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have several csv files with approximately the following structure:

```
name,title,status,1,2,3
name,title,status,4,5,6
name,title,status,7,8,9
```

Most of the `name` columns is the same in all files, only the columns 1,2,3,4... are different.
I need to take turns adding new columns to existing and new rows, as well as updating the remaining rows each time.
For example, I have 2 tables:

```
name,title,status,1,2,3
Foo,Bla-bla-bla,10,45.6,12.3,45.2
Bar,Too-too,13,13.4,22.6,75.1
```

```
name,title,status,4,5,6
Foo,Bla-bla-bla,14,25.3,125.3,5.2
Fobo,Dom-dom,20,53.4,2.9,11.3
```

And at the output I expect a table:

```
name,title,status,1,2,3,4,5,6
Foo,Bla-bla-bla,14,45.6,12.3,45.2,25.3,125.3,5.2
Bar,Too-too,13,13.4,22.6,75.1,,,
Fobo,Dom-dom,20,,,,53.4,2.9,11.3
```

I did not find anything similar, who can tell how I can do this?

Comment: `merge` on `name, title, status`?

Comment: why do you have status being 10 for the first and 14 for the second yet you take 14 instead of 10 in the results?

Comment: @Onyambu yes, it is

Comment: what is the idea?

Comment: @Onyambu I have files with reports for months and every month the status changed, as a result I need the status from the last file

Comment: good. then will upload an answer in a second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to keep just one version of `['name', 'title', 'status']` and from your example, you prefer to keep the last `'status'` encountered.

I'd use `pd.concat` and follow that up with a `groupby` to filter out duplicate status.

```
df = pd.concat([
    pd.read_csv(fp, index_col=['name', 'title', 'status'])
    for fp in ['data1.csv', 'data2.csv']
], axis=1).reset_index('status').groupby(level=['name', 'title']).last()

df

                  status     1     2     3     4      5     6
name title                                                   
Bar  Too-too          13  13.4  22.6  75.1   NaN    NaN   NaN
Fobo Dom-dom          20   NaN   NaN   NaN  53.4    2.9  11.3
Foo  Bla-bla-bla      14  45.6  12.3  45.2  25.3  125.3   5.2
```

Then `df.to_csv()` produces

```
name,title,status,1,2,3,4,5,6
Bar,Too-too,13,13.4,22.6,75.1,,,
Fobo,Dom-dom,20,,,,53.4,2.9,11.3
Foo,Bla-bla-bla,14,45.6,12.3,45.2,25.3,125.3,5.2
```

Comment: with this solution, a lot of data disappeared from their final file, although in the original they are https://pasteboard.co/IP3AvTs.jpg https://pasteboard.co/IP3AACK.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Keep merging them:

```
df = None
for path in ['data1.csv', 'data2.csv']:
    sub_df = pd.read_csv(path)

    if df is None:
        df = sub_df
    else:
        df = df.merge(sub_df, on=['name', 'title', 'status'], how='outer')
```

Comment: with this solution, a lot of data disappeared from their final file, although in the original they are https://pasteboard.co/IP3tGzB.jpg